# Difference between main(void) and main() in C

Tags: c, program-entry-point

Can anyone tell me the difference between `int main()` and `int main(void)`? Why do both of them work and what is the default argument to `int main()`?

Answer (score 18):

No difference under ordinary circumstances. This is no 'default argument to main()', since it has no arguments at all.

Here's the un-ordinary circumstance. If you write your own call to main, then `()` will permit you to pass it any parameters you like, while `(void)` will force you to pass it none. Still, none of this matters in terms of the 99.99999999% case, which is main being invoked by the runtime to launch your program. The runtime neither knows nor cares if you write `()` or `(void)`.

If you code the standard `int main(int argc, char **argv)` you will get your command-line parameters in there.

Comment: +1 -- in C++ there is no difference, but there is a slight difference in C. It's minor though.

Comment: `"No difference"`, read Billy's post.

Comment: @Billy: This question has been tagged C not C++.

Comment: @Prasoon: Yes, I know. I still found that this answer is correct in C++ to be of merit. Also, just because there technically is a difference in C doesn't mean that it's a difference that is commonly used or matters. Therefore I think this is a good answer and deserves an upvote.

Comment: @Billy ONeal : This answer is not technically 100% correct(as you said) if you take C (tag) into consideration. But still I would not upvote this answer. I liked your answer BTW and have upvoted it.

Comment: Well, OK. There is a difference if you actually write a call to main. One edit coming up.

Answer (score 8):

`main()` allows you to call main with any number of parameters. `main(void)` forces you to call main with no parameters. So:

```
main(foo, bar);
```

Is fine with `main()` but not with `main(void)` - the compiler generates an error.

Now if you're specifically asking about the program's entry point, it doesn't really make a difference; in either case, you won't have the arguments to the program (argc, argv, envp) available.

Comment: +1 -- note that `envp` is a nonstandard extension.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: But allowed by the standard in §5.1.2.2.1.1.

Comment: @Matt: I never said it wasn't allowed. I just said it was not in the standard.

Answer (score 4):

From a practical viewpoint, there's no real difference. With `int main(void)`, you're explicitly stating that `main` takes no parameters, so you can't invoke it with any. With `int main()`, you're leaving open the possibility of invoking `main` with some parameters.

However, except in strange situations like code golf or intentionally obfuscated code, you don't invoke `main` anyway -- it's the entry point to the program, so it's automatically invoked by the startup code. The startup code will pass the command line arguments anyway, so your choices don't change how it's invoked, only whether you use or ignore the parameters that get passed.

The standard does specifically allow you to define `main` with or without parameters (§5.1.2.2.1/1):

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>   parameters:

```
    int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;

Though it's outside the tags specified, in C++ the situation is slightly different. In C, a function declaration like:

```
int f();
```

specifies that `f` is a function returning an `int`, but gives *no* information about the number or type of parameters `f` might expect (this is included primarily for compatibility with old code -- at one time, this was the *only* way to declare a function in C). In C++, that same declaration explicitly declares `f` as a function that takes no parameters, so attempting to invoke `f` with one or more parameters cannot invoke this function (it must either invoke another overload or produce an error if no suitable overload is found).

Comment: @Jens: No, I simply didn't get into that, because it wasn't relevant to the question at hand. Yes, there might be other possible ways for main to be invoked, but at least those two are definitely allowed. Yes, it could conceivably return some other type, but the OP seems concerned only with parameters, not return type.

Comment: Sorry if you felt offended. What follows from this phrase, though, that an implementation might even allow the version `int main()` with any number of parameters.

Comment: @JerryCoffin , quick question. How would you invoke an Overload if the function is f( ) ?     I was looking at this locklessinc(dot)com/articles/overloading/ example but it seems like you need a parameter for that. Thanks

Comment: @BluePython: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking.