# i can't find the error syntax in loop for: c

Tags: c

I have an exercise asks me to correct the syntactic error, I tried to correct but every time I want to compile it shows me an error in the for loop.

(the exercise allows for counting and displays the number of vowel letters in a sentence entered by the user, the user indicates the end of the entry by typing '*')

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
char c;
char TV[5];
int k;
for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
 {
 TV[k]=0;
  }
 printf("Entrer un texte. Tapez le caractére * pour sortire. \n");
 c = getchar();
while(c!='*')
{
  switch (c) {
     case 'A': TV[0]++;
     case 'a': TV[0]++;
     case 'E': TV[1]++;
     case 'e': TV[1]++;
     case 'I': TV[2]++;
     case 'i': TV[2]++;
     case 'O': TV[3]++;
     case 'o': TV[3]++;
     case 'U': TV[4]++;
     case 'u': TV[4]++;
    default: c = getchar();

   }
 }
 printf("a \t e \t i \t o \t u \n");
 for(k=0;k<5;k++)
 {
  printf("%d \t",TV[k]);
 }
 }
```

error message:

```
mariem@MIGI:~/Bureau/syt_exp$ gcc Tp6-lesChaines-Exercice1.c
Tp6-Channels-Exercise1.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
 main(){
 ^~~~
mariem@MIGI:~/Bureau/syt_exp$ ./Tp6-lesChaines-Exercice1.c
./Tp6-Channels-Exercise1.c: line 6: syntax error near the unexpected symbol "("
./Tp6-Channels-Exercise1.c: line 6: `for (k = 0; k <5; k ++) '
```

I think it's better now.

Comment: post your code rathar than posting image with code because image will not visible but code is

Comment: Please include the code/error message in the post

Comment: Stackoverflow should deactivate image upload for users with lower reputation.

Comment: @ThomasSablik No, that is a poor expectation. There are cases where the image is coherent part of the post. It's just that, code should not be posted as images - that's it.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, images can be very important for a question but I rarely see an image as coherent part of a question asked by a user with reputation < 50. Comments are limited to privileged users. Images should be too

Comment: @ThomasSablik You know, comments are always allowed for own posts, irrespective of the rep. How's a question any different?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Comments on others posts are limited to avoid misuse. Here we have a perfect example for misuse of images by an inexperienced user. Images as code from inexperienced user are common on SO

Comment: @ThomasSablik I thought I was talking about own posts - as a question is a "own post" from OP.

Comment: @SouravGhosh A new user can't comment another users question to ask for details. He has to gain some reputation. Same thing would be good for usage of images. I've never seen a user with reputation > 100 posting an image of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things...

1- to fix the warning - `main(){` should be `int main(){` OR even `void main(){` works, but return type `int` is the most standard here. input parameters are optional - i.e. argv/argc.

2- after compilation (which you are doing correctly), without specifying an executable name, the default .exe produced by the compiler is either `a.out` or `a.exe`. to run, type `./a.exe` on the command line.

*Note - by doing those 2 things, I have confirmed that the program runs.*

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a syntax error. And I can't copy the code to check with my compiler. However:

`main` should be declared as

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Your loop: `while (c=='*')`?? You mean `while (c!='*')`.

And: a `case` should be terminated with a `break;`, otherwise execution just continues.

Comment: I mean while (c!=' *' ) I have already fixed it, and  I don't understand why i have to put break after case ???

Comment: Read about `switch`: without a `break` the next statement will be executed, so after `case 'A': TV[0]++;` the `TV[0]++;` will be performed belinging to `case 'a':`

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't have declarated type of main()?

```
int main()
```

Comment: and why dont you post this as a comment, rather than as an answer?

Comment: we can write main() or int main(), no problem just at the end of code you must write return 0 with int.

Comment: This question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543428/in-c-difference-between-main-and-int-main

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute the C source file directly in the shell, as if it was a shell script.  C needs to be compiled, and then you execute the file created by the compiler.

The default name for this that GCC produces is `a.out`, so execute it with `./a.out`

Comment: OP did compile it but he executed the source instead of the binary file

Comment: i tried with int main() and  it compiled but it stay give me the error message :  linge2: syntax error near the unexpected symbol "("

Comment: @MIGI as MrZebra said: 1. Compile your code (`gcc Tp6-Channels-Exercise1.c`) and 2. execute the binary file (`./a.out`). Don't execute the source file (don't `./Tp6-Channels-Exercise1.c`). This is the correct answer to your problem.

Comment: oh yes all this moment I executed the source file ,it work now thanks :)

Comment: @MIGI Great ^.^  You can click the check mark next to the answer to accept it as being correct