# Is main with parameter list of void different from main with an empty parameter list?

Tags: c, program-entry-point, void

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the type of the main function in C and c++ left to the user to define?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define)

What is a **void** ? Anyone provide some examples, proper use of **void** ? And what is the difference when we write `void main (void)` or `main()` ?

Comment: I suggest reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type
It contains useful information like this sentence: "The void type may also appear as the sole argument of a function prototype **to indicate that the function takes no arguments**."

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3711048/1284631 (this question is a duplicate)

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate at all.

Answer (score 13):

In C, in general, `(void)` means no arguments required in function call, while `()` means unspecified number of arguments.

e.g.

```
void foo(void)
{
   // body
}

void bar()
{
    //body
}
```

In calling enviroment,

```
foo();  // Correct 
foo(1); // Incorrect
bar();  // Correct
bar(1); // Also correct
```

This was the general explanation.

But for your case for main() , C99 Standard says that,

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>
> The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>   `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`

or

> with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared): 
>   `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }` or equivalent;

or

> in some other implementation-defined manner.

So, in this `void main(void)` return type should be `int`.

And at last , for `main()`, 
return type is not given so implicitly return type would be `int`.

Comment: So `void bar()` is same as `void bar(...)`?

Comment: @anishsane : No,that's called variable number of arguments and to implement this `bar(...)` at least one argument is required which is the first argument and then only it will take `...` so correct way is          `bar(char *,...)`

Comment: I read many of the comments and questions on voids in this website. I thought "void main(void)" does not return any value. One person says that it should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @JosephLee : yes, It must be avoided , see the standard I have mentioned in my answer.`main()` should have only two types of definitions and `The implementation declares no prototype for this function`

Comment: Plus, value returned by main is returned to the OS, as the exit status of process. Hence main MUST return a value.

Comment: @anishsane : I was also typing the same , this return status will tell you the execution of program is done successfully or it got terminated in the middle, And we follow the convention of `0` return value means success and any `non-zero` means error. In Linux terminal you can check the exit status of the previous command by `echo $?` , which is nothing but the return value of previous program

Comment: Implicit int was removed in C99, which you cite. So main() without a specified return type will not compile. Also, void main() is perfectly fine on free running systems, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define/5296593#5296593).

Comment: @anishsane Nobody has mentioned whether this is hosted (OS) or not. Also see C11 5.1.2.2.3: `reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0.`. So main() is a special case that doesn't follow the logic of other functions.

Comment: @Lundin: Then how does one explain this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727051 ? Perhaps, **we & our compilers do not stick to all the C** ***standards*** in our day-to-day coding.

Comment: @anishsane Most likely because the compiler that was used followed the older version of the standard, C89. As a programmer, it is your duty to pick a compiler that follows the standard you intend to write the program in. If you write code according to C99 but compile on a C89 compiler, then that is a bug caused by the programmer, not the compiler.

Comment: @ anishsane. main needs a return type of int is mandatory in **Hosted environment**, but not in **Freestanding environment**.Freestanding is something without an OS.

Answer (score 2):

Excluding the return type of the main as in

```
main(){
}
```

doesn't mean that it's a `void` type, it depends on the compiler. I think it can be said it's generically interpreted as

```
int main(){
}
```

The `void` type tells the compiler that there is no 'entity' (no 'storage'), so

```
void func(int i)
```

takes an int but returns nothing. In the case of parameters this:

```
void func()
```

is equivalent to this:

```
void func(void)
```

which indicates more explicitly that it does not take parameters.
Different story is with the type `void *` which **is** a type, a pointer to something dimensionless.

Comment: ??? If void func(int i) takes an integer but returns nothing, then what is the use? It seems it does nothing.

Comment: no, it's very common, for example for interacting with the hardware

Comment: Or more likely, void func() alters private variables declared as static at file scope.

Comment: "doesn't mean that it's a void type, it depends on the compiler", yes if it is a C90 compiler, it will be equivalent to int main(). If it is a standard C compiler, it will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, **void** is a data type, which basically used with method declaration. It means **nothing** or **no type**. Eg:

1) `int myFunc(void)` -- the function takes nothing.

2) `void myFunc(int)` -- the function returns nothing

3) `void* data;` -- 'data' is a pointer to data of unknown type, and cannot be dereferenced

Comment: I am beginning to understand what a void is in your explanations 1 and 2. Thank you. However, I do not understand what is a pointer. What is dereferenced mean?

Comment: @JosephLee sorry for using pointer. But, i just wanna to show you, where and how can we use void. If you don't know about pointer, then leave that part. Just concentrate of this part, `void` means `no type`

Comment: There is no reason to apologize. I want to learn. If you can say anything further, it will be very appreciated. If not, I will ask better questions about it later.

Comment: As you said, you are beginner, so better to start step by step. Pointer is little tough to understand, so better, clear your basic first. And, Learner are always welcome in StackOverFlow. :)

Answer (score 1):

Void means "emptyness". In your example of void main() it means that the functions main() does not return a value. I feel obliged tell you that void main() should be avoided (no pun intended) at all costs, use int main() instead. int main() makes sure your program can return a value of type int to the OS on close. There are numerous other uses of void, check out [this website](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/) if you want to read more about this.

Comment: I checked the website, but I have heard that C and C++ are vastly different. I want to learn more about voids in terms of C.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't read the tag, sorry :)

Comment: @Kevin void main() should be avoided on hosted systems (programs running on an OS), because it will not compile on such systems.

Answer (score 0):

`void` is a data type with no values.  It is also an *incomplete* data type that cannot be completed.  When used as a return type for a function, it indicates that the function does not return a value:

```
void foo(int x);
```

When used as a parameter list, it indicates that the function takes no arguments:

```
void bar(void);
```

This is different from an empty parameter list, which indicates that the function takes an *unspecified* number of arguments (in C; in C++, an empty parameter list is the same as using `void`):

```
void bletch();
```

No object (variable) can be typed `void`.  However, you can declare pointers of type `void *`: these are "generic" pointers, and can be converted to and from other pointer types without an explicit cast.  The standard memory allocation functions `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` all return `void *`:

```
double *darr = malloc(sizeof *darr * rows);
```

In a hosted implementation (basically, anything with an operating system), `main` must be declared as

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) // the parameter names can be whatever you want,
                                // but argc and argv are the usual convention;
                                // char **argv is equivalent to char *argv[]
```

or in *some other implementation-defined manner*; an implementation *may* accept

```
void main()
```

as a legitimate signature for `main`, *but it must explicitly document that somewhere*.