# What if I omit the return type of main function in C?

Tags: c

Before anyone may mark it duplicate of related questions. I emphasize I *DO* have read all those questions. But I still have some interrogations(yep, some little pedantic :) )

**For C**

Some conclusions:

```
1. In C89(C90), this is _undefined_ .
2. In C99(or C11), a type of int is madatory; control flow reached the closing } 
   will return a value of 0.
```

Here comes my interrogations.

1. In [c89](http://www.vmunix.com/~gabor/c/draft.html), I have found nothing about **undefined**, but **unspecified**?

   **Detail:** The related parts in **[C89](http://www.vmunix.com/~gabor/c/draft.html)** are **5.1.2.2.1  Program startup** and **5.1.2.2.3  Program termination** (**NOTE** : both are under the **5.1.2.2  Hosted environment** section, within which our later discussion is limitted)

   **Cite:**  -- 5.1.2.2.3  Program termination --

   `A return from the initial call to the main function  is
      equivalent  to  calling  the  exit  function  with the value
      returned by the main function as its argument.10  If  the  }
      that   terminates   the   main   function  is  reached,  the
      termination status  returned  to  the  host  environment  is
      unspecified.`

   Just note that part: **If the } that terminates ...** , it clearly says 
    that if we omit the return type - thus the } will be reached at -
    the termination status is **unspecified**

   According the definition of the standard of **undefined** and **unspecified**,
    Should I say that it gives **unspecified value** since whatever it return is a 
    legal int value, but the **consequese is undefined**-we could not predict what value
    will lead to what catastrophic consequese?
2. In c99, a type of int is madatory, but `gcc --std=c99` given a test without int type(no return type actually) gives only **waring:return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’** ,but not **error** ?

   **Detail:**  the related parts are the same as that in c89.

   **Cite:** -- 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup --

   `It shall be defined with a return type of int and ...`

   and -- 4. Conformance --

   `1. In this International Standard, ‘‘shall’’ is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, ‘‘shall not’’ is to be interpreted as a
   prohibition.`

   So **shall** should be interpreted as **madatory** in this standard, why gcc with swith **--std=c99** violated this?

Comment: Report a bug to gcc maintainers.

Comment: use `-pedantic-errors` to make ISO violations errors in GCC

Comment: `gcc -std=c99` is only a loose approximation, it still swallows most of the c89 stuff that was removed, and extensions. However, it gives a diagnostic, and more is not required. If you want a good approximation to the standard, also use `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Yes the return type is mandatory, and my quite old version of GCC (4.4.5) warns about it with `-std=c99` or higher.

Comment: unspecified is a [Synonym](http://thesaurus.com/browse/unspecified) of undefined

Comment: @ Cubbi thanks ! It DOES give error with this switch.

Comment: [Recently posted, related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876868/void-mainvoid-vs-main)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C89/90 still has the implicit int rule, so `main()` is equivalent to `int main()`. By leaving off the return type, you've implicitly defined the return type as `int`. Some may consider this sloppy, but it's strictly conforming (i.e., involves no implementation defined, undefined or unspecified behavior).

For C99, the implicit `int` rule has been removed, so `main()` isn't defined. *However*, a compiler is only required to "issue a diagnostic" upon encountering a violation of a `Shall` or `Shall not` clause -- it's still free to continue compiling after issuing the diagnostic. Exactly what constitutes a diagnostic is implementation defined. As such, all that's needed for gcc to conform in this respect is documentation to say that the warning it issues is to be considered a diagnostic.

Edit: "implicit `int`" in the C89/90 standard isn't really a single rule in a single place -- it's spread around in a couple of places. The primary one is §6.5.2.1, where it says:

> -- `int`, `signed`, `signed int`, or no type specifiers

This is part of a list, where all the items on each line of the list are considered equivalent, so this is saying that (unless otherwise prohibited) lack of a type specifier is equivalent to specifying (signed) `int`.

For function parameters, there's a separate specification (at §6.7.1) that: "Any parameter that is not declared has type `int`."

Comment: [C89/90 still has the implicit int rule] Could you give me the citation in Standard please?

Comment: @larmbr: See edited answer [I hate standards printed on paper].

Answer (score 0):

Even in case of a constraint violation, the only thing a C compiler must issue is a "diagnostic". It is then allowed to continue and to produce an executable program.

Comment: Thanks. I use the -pedantic-erros switch then it will complains error

Answer (score 0):

> Just note that part: **If the } that terminates** ... , it clearly says that if we omit the return type

No, it doesn't. It says what happens when you omit the `return exitStatus;` from the end of `main()`.

> According the definition of the standard of ** undefined ** and unspecified, Should I say that it gives unspecified value since whatever it return is a legal int value, but the consequese is undefined-we could not predict what value will lead to what catastrophic consequese.

No. It means that you don't know what the return status code of your program will be. The behavior is, however, not undefined: your program terminates. With what kind of result code, that's a different question.

> [...] gives only waring: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’, but not error?

That's how it's implemented. In old C (C89) - and with some newer compilers as well - if you omit the return type of a function, it is assumed to be `int` (so even the warning looks a bit problematic).

> So shall should be interpreted as madatory in this standard, why gcc with swith --std=c99 violated this?

Probably yes. Note that GCC is a non-conformant implementation except if you use `-ansi -pedantic`, so in theory, any program compiled without these flags has undefined behavior. But that's theory...

Comment: Yep, but if a main has no return type, then } will be reached ,which is still an interpretation of the standard, isn't it.(of course, yours may be the original meaning.)

Comment: @larmbr `main()` having no return type and having no `return 0;` statement at its end have nothing to do with each other. You can do both of them, or just one of them, or neither one (the optimal). You misunderstood the wording of the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this is some sort of C90 standard reference mistake. I have no idea whether the document you link to is equivalent to the actual ISO C90 standard or not.

Apparently, this particular issue has changed from undefined, to unspecified, to well-defined over the years.

In early drafts of ANSI-C "for the X3.J11 working group", you will find the following text:

> 2.1.2.2 Hosted environment
>
> "Program termination"
>
> A return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent
>   to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main
>   function as its argument.  If the main function executes a return that
>   specifies no value, the termination status returned to the host
>   environment is **undefined**.

Comment: Quite good tips, thanks. As for the cited c89 standard, it is just a draft, maybe it is not the final print, but I could not find it.

Comment: @larmbr Actually the link you posted seems more like some sort of post-C90 draft, since it lists normative standards from 1993.