# Array of structure as arguments and acessing members confusion

Tags: c, arguments, structure

```
typedef struct Calendar {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
}Calendar;

typedef struct Person {
    char name[40];
    int age;
    float salary;
    Calendar birth;
}Person;
void add(Person * a, int * tam);
```

If I want to pass structure as argument and modify its original value I have to pass as pointer, but a array of structure shouldn't be passed as pointer of a pointer like a array of array? Why the compiler works with a pointer and gives error with a pointer of a pointer?

```
for (int i = 0; i < *tam + 1; i++)
{
        printf("Insert your name:\n");
        fgets(name, 30, stdin);
        *a[i].name = name;
}
```

The last line gives  warning C4047: char differs in levels of indirections. If I remove '*' it doesn't compile. How do I correctly access a array member from a array of structure?

EDIT 1: To clarify here is the full `add()` function and `main()` function.

```
void add(Person * a, int * tam) {

    char name[30];
    int op = 0;
    int c, day = 0, month = 0, year = 0, Calendar = -1;
    float sal = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < *tam + 1; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert your name:\n");
        fgets(name, 30, stdin);
        *a[i].name = name;

        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            ;
        do
        {
            printf("Insert %s's age:\n", name);
            scanf("%d", &op);
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ;
            if (!op)
                printf("invalid age!\n");
            else
                a[i].age = op;
        } while (op <= 0);
        do
        {
            printf("Insert %s's salary:\n", name);
            scanf("%f", &sal);
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ;
            if (sal < 0)
                printf("Invalid salary!\n");
            else
                a[i].salary = sal;

        } while (sal < 0);
        do
        {
            printf("Insert %s's date birth\n", name);
            printf("Day:\n");
            scanf("%d", &day);
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ;
            printf("Month:\n");
            scanf("%d", &month);
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ;
            printf("Year:\n");
            scanf("%d", &year);
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ;

            if ((day > 0 && day < 31) && (month > 0 && month < 12) && (year > 0))
            {
                Calendar = 1;
                a[i].birth.day = day;
                a[i].birth.month = month;
                a[i].birth.year = year;
            }
            else
                printf("Invalid calendar!\n");

        } while (Calendar != 1);

    }
    *tam++;
}

main() {
    Person book[10];
    int c, tam = 0;
    char op, out = 0;
    while (!out)
    {

        do
        {
            printf("1: Insert a profile\n");
            printf("2: Change a profile\n");
            printf("3: Erase a Profile\n");
            printf("4: Show all profiles\n");
            printf("5: Search\n");
            printf("0: Exit\n");
            scanf("%c", &op);
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ;

        } while (op < '0' || op > '5');

        switch (op)
        {
        case '1':
            add(book, &tam);
            break;
        case '2':

            break;
        case '3':

            break;
        case '4':
            read(book, &tam);
            break;
        case '5':

            break;
        case '0':
            out = 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is `tam`? Maybe a helpful name would help understand what you want to do. Also serves as documentation for the code. `a` is also a bad name for `struct Person` I think

Comment: You remove the '\*'.  But then you have a *different* problem: whole arrays such as `a[i].name` cannot be assigned to.  In that particular case, perhaps you want `strcpy()`.

Comment: Please show the full function that contains the for loop.  Is it supposed to be part of `add()`?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito yes the `for` loop is inside the `add()` function, and `*tam` variable is just to count the size of  the structure array

Comment: @JohnBollinger probably you mean `strncpy()`.  Usually you should avoid `strcpy()`

Comment: @JohnBollinger If I have to modify a array member the way is strncpy()?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `void add(int n, struct Person a[n]);`

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I mean I dont understand why not `void add (Person ** a, int * size)`

Comment: A) why do you want `tam` to be a pointer? B) why do you want to use pointers instead of an array for `a`, if you are trying to deal with an array?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito  `tam` is the index that will be passed to main. B) dont know if this is bad programming habit, but wont i pass the adress either way? `void something( int a[])`  or `void something(int * a)`

Comment: I still think you want this `void add(int tam, struct Person a[tam]);` and then `strncpy(a[i].name, name, BUFF_SIZE - 1)`

Comment: Yes, in the end it is the same (not in arrays with more than 1 dimension, but true in this case), but it is a lot more clear, and you wouldn't have had many of this problems if you had used the array form.

Comment: How can it be the index and the size at the same time?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito srry `tam` is the array size not index

Comment: Are you modifying `*tam` inside the function? If not, you shouldn't use a pointer. Also, why are you iterating until `i < *tam+1` and not `i < *tam`? You will be accessing one element outside the array size.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I edit the question to clarify the current situation with `main()` and `add()` . I declared `tam = 0` thats why i need `for(int i = 0; i < *tam +1;i++)` and it isnt complete yet, because my confusion with structures.

Comment: Problems:  A) You have an `int` named `Calendar`, and also a `typedef struct Calendar Calendar;`  You should rename the former to `int calendar`.

Comment: B)  If you are not very confident with `struct`s and are still learning them, I suggest that you start without using `typedef`.  It only serves to obscure the `struct`.

Comment: C)  You should pass the maximum size of the array, so that `add()`doesn't try to write more than it, and to keep track of the number of elements used, another variable (by ref):  `void add(size_t n, struct Person a[n], int *tam);`

Comment: D)  Please do NOT declare `main()` like that.  First of all, the implicit `int` is deprecated (read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935104/what-if-i-omit-the-return-type-of-main-function-in-c).
  There are **only** 2 portable forms accepted in standard:
`int main(void)`
and
`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
(read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108208/6872717).  Other implementation defined prototypes for `main()` may be accepted, but you shouldn't rely on them without a good reason.

Comment: E)  I guess you want your `add()` function to only add one element to the array, so I don't see why you need the `for` loop.  I think you may want `strncpy(a[*tam].name, name, n - 1);  (*tam)++;` and get rid of the `for` loop.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito you are right. the `for` loop is absolutely unnecessary, thanks.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &op);`:  You should add a space just before the `%c`:  `scanf(" %c", &op);` (read this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito, regarding "Usually you should avoid strcpy()": no, I do not accept that as a general rule.  It is a question of your requirements and what you can rely upon about your data.  Whereas `strcpy()` may overrun array bounds if you are not careful, `strncpy()` may leave the destination unterminated, setting the stage for a *future* buffer overrun (and it may itself overrun the buffer, too, if you don't get its length right).  In practice, the failure behavior attending `strncpy()` can be worse than the failure behavior attending `strcpy()`.

Comment: The `-1` is exactly for that purpose:  It means "`strncpy()` please do leave one last `char` to write a `'\0'` there".

Comment: Of course, `strlcpy()` is better, but it isn't standard (I hope it is in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prototype for your function should make clear that it works with an array:

```
void add(size_t n, struct Person arr[n], int *tam);
```

This way, you know the size of the array (`n`), and you can make sure that you don't try to access beyond that size, which would end up in a `segmentation fault` if you are lucky (read this: [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)).

---

The `for` loop would then loop over the array:

```
for (int i = 0, *tam = 0; i < n; i++, (*tam)++) {
    printf("Insert your name:\n");
    fgets(name, 30, stdin);
    /* a[i].name = name; */
}
(*tam)++;
```

You **need** the parentheses around `(*tam)++` because of operator precedance (read this: [How to increment a pointer address and pointer's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208021/how-to-increment-a-pointer-address-and-pointers-value)).

---

As for the access to the `struct`s inside the array, you have to know that you are accessing an array of `struct`s;  that is just many `struct`s put together, as an array of `int`s would be:

`a` is an array of `struct`s.

`a[i]` is the `i`th struct in the array.

`a[i].name` is the element `name` in the struct `a[i]`.

---

To copy a string into another, you have to copy it element by element, because internally they are an array of `char`s, and because of the way arrays work in C, you can not copy them with `=` but by iterating and copying element by element.

In case of normal arrays, function `memcpy()` does that for you (read this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html).

When you are dealing with strings, the function you want to use to copy them is `strncpy()` (read this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3p.html).

The correct usage of `strncpy()` is explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14067026/6872717

Basically you would use it like this:

```
strncpy(a[i].name, name, n - 1);
```

so your `for` loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0, *tam = 0; i < n; i++, (*tam)++) {
    printf("Insert your name:\n");
    fgets(name, 30, stdin);
    strncpy(a[i].name, name, 40 - 1);
    a[i].name[40 - 1] = '\0';
}
(*tam)++;
```

---

This is more a comment, and I may remove it later if it isn't what you want, but here I can format better the code:

I am not sure why the `for` loop is there, but for the context, I guess this function is meant to only write into one `struct` in the array.  So maybe instead of the `for` loop you may want something like this:

```
if (*tam = (n - 1))
    goto err_array_full;
if (*tam > (n - 1)  ||  *tam < 0)
    goto err_invalid_index;

printf("Insert your name:\n");
fgets(name, 30, stdin);
strncpy(a[*tam].name, name, 40 - 1);
a[*tam].name[40 - 1] = '\0';
(*tam)++;
```

---

Final note:  I used `40` in `strncpy()` because you used `40` to create the array, but that *should* be a macro which you would use in both places so that when you change the size of the array you don't forget to change it also in `strncpy()`, which would introduce a bug.  With a macro you are safe because you only change one number and all your code is updated.

Comment: About the prototype if I pass a single structure as argument to modify it value it would be `void add(Person * a)`. What I don't understand is why when it is an array of structure the compiler gives error with this `void add(Person *a[])`, but works with this instead `void add(Person a[])` or `void add(Person * a)`. An array of array would be `void func(int a[][])` or `void func(int *a[])`. Doesn't  both, structure or array, pass arguments as references? What am I missing?

Comment: No, if you pass a `struct` your are really passing a copy of it (read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13555817/6872717)

Comment: So yes, your new prototype `void add(struct Person *a)` would work, if you passed a pointer to a struct like this: `add(&(book[tam]));` but then you would need to increment `tam` in main.  Also you would need to use it differently inside of `add()`: `strncpy(a->name, name, 40 - 1);` (which is short for `strncpy((*a).name, name, 40 - 1);`) (read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist/13366168).

Comment: Read better this one about the `->` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575050/6872717

Comment: Passing a `struct` to a function behaves like passing an `int`. It just makes a copy of it, and if you want to modify it you need to pass a pointer to it.  Arrays are the only weird things that behave differently when passed to a function: instead of passing a copy, they pass a pointer to its first element, so that you can modify them without explicitly using pointers.  And therefore you need to use `const` if you want to pass an array that cannot be modified.

Comment: So, if you want to pass a copy of a `struct`, you use:
`void add(struct Person a);`
and use it like this:
`x = a.age;` (note that this is a copy, so usually you would only read from it).
  If you want to pass a pointer to a single `struct`, you use:
`void add(struct Person *a);`
and use it like this:
`a->age = 7;`.
  And if you want to pass an array of `struct`s, you use:
`void add(size_t n, struct Person a[n]);`
and use it like this:
`a[i].age = 7;`

Comment: Usually when passing `struct`s to a function you don't want to pass a copy of them even if you only want to read from them, because that would use more RAM and would be slow;  The solution is to pass a `const struct Struct_Tag *some_struct` so that you pass a pointer to the original struct, but you don't allow the function to write into it.

Comment: This: `struct Person *a[]` is an array of pointers to `struct`s.  You clearly do NOT have an array of pointers to `struct`s.  The whole thing of considering that arrays are pointers is misleading you.  Arrays decay to pointers, but that shouldn't bother you, and `struct`s have nothing to do with pointers.